# Display human readable time from EPOCH time - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have a epoch time in my MySql table

```
------------
update_time
------------
1401362621
1401362864
```

I want to convert this time to a human readable format. I have written in my select query, which is not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(update_time) FROM table_name";
```

Comment: Did you bother looking up what `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` does exactly? And while you were at it, maybe read further for related date/time functions? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: i am stuck up in putting it in query.

Comment: so you can use it in php

Answer (score 1):

Use the date function:

```
$t=1401362621; // your time here
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t); // format your date
```

You can use other formatting options like what here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks.. but how do i put it in my SELECT query?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that either in php or in mysql way:

Its upto you to choose :

Mysql way:

```
  SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(update_time) FROM table_name";
```

see the doc: [Mysql date and time function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

PHP way:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1401362864');
```